# How do I write to a file with a Perl Catalyst app?

Tags: perl, catalyst

Inside of my Root.pm I have a sub index function as such:

```
sub index :Path :Args(0) {

    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

    #basic file IO attempt to write to a file
    my $file = 'test3.log';
    open(my $fh, '>>', $file);
    print $fh "I can write to a file\n";
    close $fh;

    $c->stash({
        template    => 'index.tt',
    });

    #debug that doesnt work for some reason
    $c->log->debug('Does this actually work?');    
}
```

How can you write to a file that is in the same or different directory as the pm that calls it?

Comment: Just give the complete path to te file.

Comment: Don't! Perl Modules are not data. Don't mix your data and your application. Specify a directory to store data in in your catalyst configuration, then use that configuration to find a suitable path.

Comment: In this case, it will be created a file test3.log in the root folder of your project.If you want a specific file as M42 said : "Just give the complete path to te file"

Comment: Chances are your web server does not have permission to write a file in the current working directory for the server. Add some error checking to your `open` call, e.g. `open my $fh, '>>', $file or die "open $file: $!";` and see what error you get.

Comment: Alternatively to `or die`, just add [`use autodie;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) to the beginning of your module, right after the [`use strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) pragmas.  Then you would've gotten a meaningful error message and recognized your need to specify a full path or adjust your directory permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You can always find the root of your application with `MyApp->path` but when you are generating files at runtime you might want to avoid putting that stuff in the application area since you're permissions to that might be different in production from development.

What I've seen a lot of people do is put that stuff under `/var`.

Answer (score 0):

You propably did write a file to the "current" directory. But this directory is not where your `Root.pm` is located. In case you start up your Catalyst with the the webserver script in the `scripts` directory, you will find `test3.log` where you started the script from.

To find out the directory, where your current File is located, use `__FILE__` and extrect the path name:

```
use File::Basename;

# ...

sub index :Path :Args(0) {

    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

    #basic file IO attempt to write to a file
    my $dirname  = dirname(__FILE__);
    my $file = $dirname.'/test3.log';
    open(my $fh, '>>', $file) or die $!;
    print $fh "I can write to a file\n";
    close $fh;

    # ...
}
```

See https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Basename for further information about the `dirname` routine.

Answer (score 0):

You should use package like [Log::Log4perl::Catalyst](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Log%3A%3ALog4perl%3A%3ACatalyst) instead of writing to disk in each method to prevent concurrent writing to the same file. It's also much more flexible, like using different level of log (debug, warn, error), different outputs, etc.